# What type of helicopter is shown in Star Wars The Last Jedi featurette?

Tags: helicopter, aircraft-identification

There is a nice [featurette](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ye6GCY_vqYk) about the new Star Wars movie The Last Jedi.

One shot (1:32) shows a helicopter in the background. What is it?

[image]

Comment: Nobody's asking the obvious question: _What's a helicopter doing in Star Wars???_  :D

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The helicopter is a **Eurocopter EC135 T2+**. The registration (just above the tail rotor) **EI-ILS** shows that this aircraft *was* registered in Ireland, this helicopter was sold to PDG HELICOPTERS in early 2016 and is now on the U.K. register as **G-GLAB**. Based on this information it suggests that this particular segment was filmed before or shortly after early 2016 when the aircraft would likely have been re-painted with the new registration.

Eurocopter are a popular "household name" in aviation with numerous models operated throughout Europe and beyond in various roles such as airborne policing, medical flights (air ambulance), and some military operations. Eurocopter now operate as "Airbus Helicopters" and subsequently the EC135 has been re-designated as the H135.

Answer (score 9):

Googling the registration EI-ILS:

- Eurocopter EC135 T2
- Irish Helicopters Ltd
- MAX. PASSENGERS 6
- YEAR OF PRODUCTION 2008
- HOMEBASE EIDW (DUB), Dublin Intl

Comment: It also looks exactly like a EC-135, so google seems to be right.

Comment: You can *read* that?

Comment: @mike Its pretty clear if you zoom in on the image.